# Can't launch application

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

When I launch my app, I has this:"Unfortunately, *App Name* has stopped." and this "Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #1: You must supply a layout_width attribute."

my axml file:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px">
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="210.9dp"
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout1">
        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/fone"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:id="@+id/imageView1" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="140dp"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0.0dp">
            <ImageButton
                android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
                android:layout_width="49.0dp"
                android:layout_height="50.8dp"
                android:id="@+id/privateButton"
                android:layout_marginRight="98.9dp"
                android:background="#00000000" />
            <ImageButton
                android:src="@drawable/logo"
                android:layout_width="75.3dp"
                android:layout_height="64.1dp"
                android:id="@+id/logoButton"
                android:layout_marginRight="113.7dp"
                android:background="#00000000" />
            <ImageButton
                android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
                android:layout_width="49.0dp"
                android:layout_height="50.8dp"
                android:id="@+id/cartButton"
                android:background="#00000000" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout />
    </FrameLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="142.7dp"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2">
        <Button
            android:text="Суші"
            android:layout_width="192.8dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:background="@drawable/sushi"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
        <Button
            android:text="Роли"
            android:layout_width="192.8dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:background="@drawable/rolli"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="142.7dp"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout3">
        <Button
            android:text="Сети"
            android:layout_width="192.8dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:background="@drawable/sets"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
        <Button
            android:text="Холодні Закуски"
            android:layout_width="192.8dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:background="@drawable/holodni"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60.2dp"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0.0dp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#f2565c"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout5">
            <ImageButton
                android:src="@drawable/back"
                android:layout_width="49.0dp"
                android:layout_height="50.8dp"
                android:id="@+id/previousButton"
                android:layout_marginRight="113.9dp"
                android:background="#00000000" />
            <ImageButton
                android:src="@drawable/home"
                android:layout_width="49.0dp"
                android:layout_height="50.8dp"
                android:id="@+id/homeButton"
                android:layout_marginRight="113.9dp"
                android:background="#00000000" />
            <ImageButton
                android:src="@drawable/next"
                android:layout_width="49.0dp"
                android:layout_height="50.8dp"
                android:id="@+id/nextButton"
                android:layout_marginLeft="0.0dp"
                android:background="#00000000" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

My Main Activity:

```html
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;

namespace Murakami
{
    [Activity(Label = "Murakami", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/logo")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
       // int count = 1;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

            // Get our button from the layout resource,
            // and attach an event to it
            //Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.MyButton);
            //button.Click += delegate { button.Text = string.Format("{0} clicks!", count++); };
            
            
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the tag

```
<LinearLayout/>
```

in 45th line. That will get it right

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with your xml file.

```
         ...
            <ImageButton
                android:src="@drawable/logo"
                android:layout_width="75.3dp"
                android:layout_height="64.1dp"
                android:id="@+id/logoButton"
                android:layout_marginRight="113.7dp"
                android:background="#00000000" />
            <ImageButton
                android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
                android:layout_width="49.0dp"
                android:layout_height="50.8dp"
                android:id="@+id/cartButton"
                android:background="#00000000" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout />  // this line is not required. DELETE this line.
```

You created a new LinearLayout but without giving any attributes to it.I assume it is accidentally.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You are using one

```
<LinearLayout />
```

in wrong way

Either remove this or put width and height attribute in it.

Make you layout like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:minWidth="25px"
android:minHeight="25px">
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="210.9dp"
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout1">
    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/fone"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:id="@+id/imageView1" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="140dp"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0.0dp">
        <ImageButton
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
            android:layout_width="49.0dp"
            android:layout_height="50.8dp"
            android:id="@+id/privateButton"
            android:layout_marginRight="98.9dp"
            android:background="#00000000" />
        <ImageButton
            android:src="@drawable/logo"
            android:layout_width="75.3dp"
            android:layout_height="64.1dp"
            android:id="@+id/logoButton"
            android:layout_marginRight="113.7dp"
            android:background="#00000000" />
        <ImageButton
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
            android:layout_width="49.0dp"
            android:layout_height="50.8dp"
            android:id="@+id/cartButton"
            android:background="#00000000" />
    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="142.7dp"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2">
    <Button
        android:text="Суші"
        android:layout_width="192.8dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:background="@drawable/sushi"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
    <Button
        android:text="Роли"
        android:layout_width="192.8dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:background="@drawable/rolli"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="142.7dp"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout3">
    <Button
        android:text="Сети"
        android:layout_width="192.8dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:background="@drawable/sets"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
    <Button
        android:text="Холодні Закуски"
        android:layout_width="192.8dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:background="@drawable/holodni"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60.2dp"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0.0dp">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#f2565c"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout5">
        <ImageButton
            android:src="@drawable/back"
            android:layout_width="49.0dp"
            android:layout_height="50.8dp"
            android:id="@+id/previousButton"
            android:layout_marginRight="113.9dp"
            android:background="#00000000" />
        <ImageButton
            android:src="@drawable/home"
            android:layout_width="49.0dp"
            android:layout_height="50.8dp"
            android:id="@+id/homeButton"
            android:layout_marginRight="113.9dp"
            android:background="#00000000" />
        <ImageButton
            android:src="@drawable/next"
            android:layout_width="49.0dp"
            android:layout_height="50.8dp"
            android:id="@+id/nextButton"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0.0dp"
            android:background="#00000000" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```